# What is the fastest way to use a binary search tree when inserting a large number of sequential files?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, sequential

I'm writing a program which sorts through folders of files and checks them against each other for duplicate names. To do this I get a list of all the file names and then run them through a binary tree. If the name exists in the tree, it marks the file as a duplicate and if it doesn't exist it adds the name to the tree.

The problem I'm running into is when a large batch of files is sequential (e.g. picture files where the entire name is identical except the final number sequentially going up) which causes the files to continually be placed on the right which in turn causes the depth of the tree to balloon. I'm looking for a way to reduce the time to process these files.

I've tried an AVL Tree but the time it takes to continually balance the tree as hundreds of thousands of files are added (and again, constantly rebalancing due to the sequential nature of the file names) ends up taking longer than simply allowing the depth to reach the tens of thousands. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Inserting into a balanced tree takes time logarithmic in the number of elements in the tree. You shouldn't even notice the accounting on only 10,000 elements. I think you could get a lot more help if you showed the code you have tried (ideally both variants)

Comment: In a balanced tree it should be logarithmic but in one that isn't being balanced the worst case for an insertion/search is O(n). For example, say you have 10,000 files and they are simply numbered 1~10000. If you insert them into a binary tree, they would continually branch right till you have a tree that has 10000 depth. The code here seems irrelevant as it's a very basic binary tree.

Comment: May I ask why do you need BST for? if you first collect all file names in an array and *then* push them to BST, why not just randomly shuffle the array to destroy that sequential nature?

Comment: I need the BST because in most cases where there isn't a large volume of sequentially numbered files, it's a faster way to compare every file against every other file for duplicates. A random shuffle to destroy the sequential nature sounds like a good idea and I'll give that a try and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Shihab, that was exactly what I needed to do!

Comment: A hash table would be much simpler. And faster, too.

Comment: Personally I think you're using the wrong algorithm for this. Instead of a binary tree I'd use a hash table. Yes, calculating the hash will take time but you're saving time on lookups. Look at implementations of generic hash tables like libghthash for how to handle hash collisions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Shihab Shahriar suggested randomly shuffling the array and that did the trick beautifully.

The tests were run on a folder containing 233,738 picture files and prior to shuffling, the sequential nature of the picture file's names resulted in the binary tree depth being 34,227 and taking just over 26 minutes to process. Various batches of picture files were resulting in an O(n) insertion and search on the binary tree. After simply shuffling the array containing all the files prior to inserting them into the binary tree, the depth was reduced to the mid 40s and the time to process the files dropped to around 2 minutes.

Thanks for the help!